# dataframe or sqlctx (sqlcontext) generated "Trying to call a package" error

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using spark 1.3.1. In PySpark, I have created a DataFrame from a RDD and registered the schema, something like this :

```
dataLen=sqlCtx.createDataFrame(myrdd, ["id", "size"])
dataLen.registerTempTable("tbl")
```

at this point everything is fine I can make a "select" query from "tbl", for example "select size from tbl where id='abc'".

Then in a Python function, I define something like :

```
def  getsize(id):
    total=sqlCtx.sql("select size from tbl where id='" + id + "'")
    return total.take(1)[0].size
```

at this point still no problem, I can do `getsize("ab")` and it does return a value.

The problem occurred  when I invoked `getsize` within a rdd, say I have a rdd named data which is of (key, value) list, when I do

```
data.map(lambda x: (x[0], getsize("ab"))
```

this  generated an error which is

> py4j.protocol.Py4JError: Trying to call a package

Any idea?

Comment: Did you add the py4j package shipped with spark to the PYTHON path?

Comment: I am pretty sure I did else I wouldn't able to invoke 'getsize("ab")" at the pyspark shell level, right?

Comment: Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't answer you question so it can be improved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn't support nested actions or transformations and `SQLContext` is not accessible outside the driver. So what you're doing here simply cannot work. It is not exactly clear what you want here but most likely a simple `join`, either on `RDDs` or `DataFrames` should do the trick.